# How to set the default font for iText7 / pdfhtml

Tags: c#, itext7, pdfhtml

Various comments are written into a PDF table. The table has one column.

The comments come from an HTML editor from a web application and contain HTML text that is output with pdfhtml.

Examples for comments:

- <div> a <b>bold</b> and an <i>italic</i> text.</div>
- <div><span style="font-size: 18px">large</span><div><div><span style="font-size: 11px">medium</span><div><div><span style="font-size: 8px">small</span></div>

The whole output should be in Verdana, but some other fonts (AgencyFB) should appear (in the spans of the second example).

The code

```
public byte[] CreateDoc()
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream))
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);

            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("Verdana", PdfEncodings.CP1252, true);
            float fontSize = 11f;

            Table table = new Table(1);
            table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph("no Html").SetFont(font).SetFontSize(fontSize)));

            string comment1 = "<div>a <b>bold</b> and an <i>italic</i> text.</div>";
            string comment2 = "<div><span style=\"font-size: 18px\">large</span><div><div><span style=\"font-size: 11px\">medium</span><div><div><span style=\"font-size: 8px\">small</span></div>";

            InsertHtmlCell(table, font, fontSize, comment1);
            InsertHtmlCell(table, font, fontSize, comment2);

            doc.Add(table);

            doc.Flush();
            doc.Close();
            pdfDoc.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }

        byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();

        return buffer;
    }
}

private void InsertHtmlCell(Table table, PdfFont f, float fontSize, string comment)
{
    var cell = new Cell(1, 1);

    // Without ConverterProperties, "times" is used
    ConverterProperties prop = new ConverterProperties();
    prop.SetFontProvider(new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, true));
    var elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(comment, prop).Cast<IBlockElement>();
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        // without the following 2 lines always "AgencyFB" is used.
        element.SetProperty(Property.FONT, f);
        element.SetProperty(Property.FONT_SIZE, new UnitValue(UnitValue.CreatePointValue(fontSize)));
        cell.Add(element);
    }

    table.AddCell(cell);
}
```

Result:
[image]

"bold", "large", "medium" and "small": AgencyFB
"italic": BookAntiqua

But the whole output should be in Verdana. How can I reach this?

Comment: I want to set the default font for the whole output to verdana - as the title says

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: What is `FontNormal.Font`? It is not iText code. The sample is not reproducible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the font provider to load all the system fonts. If you definitely don't need all of them, you can just have a white list of fonts that you want to use. In your case you need to add Verdana Regular, Verdana Bold and Verdana Italic fonts.

This is how you can do that:

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
fontProvider.addFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/verdana.ttf");
fontProvider.addFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/verdanab.ttf"); // Bold
fontProvider.addFont("C:/Windows/Fonts/verdanai.ttf"); // Italic
```

Comment: Works, but not for all cases - e.g. when you have ul or ol tags.

Comment: @Penguin so what does not work in those cases when you have `ul` or `ol` tags?